# Resync branch deleted from a fork in Stash

Tags: git, bitbucket-server, git-fork

I have two Stash repositories, one is a FORK of another one (PARENT).
I did a mistake and merged in the wrong branch (FORK.wrong-branch) some commits.
 
To fix it I decided to delete FORK.wrong-branch.
Now this branch exists only in the PARENT repository, I would like to recreate it also in my FORK, how should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull the branch from the parent repository and push it to the fork repository. Something like this:

`git fetch PARENT`

`git push FORK PARENT/branch:branch`